# Django - Query or for loop with exeption based on login user

Tags: django

Hy,

I have a page that it can be accesed only if the user have a magiclink(made with django-sesame). After open that page using that maginlink i know witch user is, because when link is generated it incorporate the user information and include in that link.

So, the issue/question : in that page i want to show the name and departemnt for all users exept the users with the same department as the login user. I don't know how to make the query in view or forloop in template with that rule.

With another words: if the user logged in is from department "hr" i want to show in the template all the users  for all department except those from "hr".
Please help me with a solution.

models.py

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    nume = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    departament = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

view.py

```
@authenticate
def pagina_secreta(request):
    
    utilizatori = User.objects.all()
    context = {'utilizatori' : utilizatori}
    return render(request, 'feedback/pagina_secreta.html', context)
```

template.html

```
     {% for d in utilizatori %}
    
        {{d.profil.nume}} {{d.profil.departament}} <br><br>
    
        {% endfor %}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the department of that person with:

```
@authenticate
def pagina_secreta(request):
    utilizatori = User.objects.exclude(
        profil__departament=request.user.profil.departament
    )
    context = {'utilizatori' : utilizatori}
    return render(request, 'feedback/pagina_secreta.html', context)
```